# Ember property doesn't update properly with multiple dependencies

Tags: ember.js

My property `sum` depends on 3 different properties (inside a model). I also have an other property that depends on `sum`. `isZero` and `sum` have a binding in a template `{{isZero}} {{sum}}`.

this is my simplified code:

```
sum: function () {
     console.log('sum is', this.get('p1') + this.get('p2') + this.get('p3'));
     return this.get('p1') + this.get('p2') + this.get('p3');
}.property('p1', 'p2', 'p3'),

p1: function () {
    console.log('update p1');
    return _data.p1;
}.property('data'),

p2: function () {
    console.log('update p2');
    return _data.p2;
}.property('data'),

p3: function () {
    console.log('update p3');
    return _data.p3;
}.property('data'),

data: {},

_data: {p1: 1, p2: 2, p3: 3},

isZero: function () {
    console.log('sum in isZero is', this.get('sum'));
    return this.get('sum') === 0;
}.property('sum'),

updateData: function () {
    this._data = {p1: 0, p2: 0, p3: 0};
    this.notifyPropertyChange('data');
}
```

Some times, when I update data, `sum` and `isZero` are not correctly updated. If I call `updateData()`, these are the prints in console:

```
> update p1
> sum is 5
> sum in isZero is 5
> update p2
> update p3
> sum is 0
```

As you can see `isZero` is not updated anymore and `sum` updates twice. My template will display isZero false and sum 0.
I know this code looks crazy but it is the closest I can show from my problem. I tried to reproduce in an ember jsbin, unfortunately it works correctly in there.

Anyone have any ideia why this is happening?

ps.: the `updateData` call is inside an ember run loop. I'm using ember version 1.9.1.

Comment: An Ember JSBin of this would be helpful, I think there might be some errors in the simplified example. You have `this._data: {p1: 0, p2: 0, p3: 0};` in your `updateData` call, did you mean to put `this.set("_data", {p1: 0, p2: 0, p3: 0}` ?

Comment: I meant `this._data = {p1: 0, p2: 0, p3: 0};`, this is part of a ember data simulator. This is my JSBin [link](http://jsbin.com/civoqe/edit?html,js,output), but unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the error there. Maybe because my real code has to much computed properties and observes.